# what media browser/player supports bookmarks in a playlist that loops

Tags: video, software-rec, bookmarks

Sometimes I decide "I want to watch the next video in this playlist".  Kodi/xbmc has a check mark that indicates "you have already watched this video" and another icon that indicates "You started watching, but quit part way through" (this feature is cool), but once I reach the end, all the videos have check marks.  If I want to watch another cycle, how do I know where I left off?

I am looking for a media player that does not just bookmark an individual video; It can also bookmark which video in a series is "next".  This functionality is already built in to streaming media services like Funimation or Crunchyroll, but I have yet to find something similar to kodi that supports this feature.

Bonus points if it supports a DVD jukebox, although I have yet to find a file format capable of representing a single episode from my Samurai Jack DVDs (title 7 chapter 1-1 is "VIII - Jack vs. Mad Jack").